# Can vimdiff show large files beyond screenful limits at once?

Tags: terminal, vimdiff, large-documents

I'd like to `diff` large files in vim using the scrollback limit set in my terminal (which is available memory), so I can, if necessary, find and review previously applied changes.

I use OS X's Terminal set to `xterm-256color` (modified, `alternate screen` is disabled).

I couldn't find any settings to make the initial windows the same size as the opened files.

**EDIT**

A workaround for single files is using [MouseTerm](https://bitheap.org/mouseterm/) to enable mouse reporting, then add to your `~/.vimrc`

```
if has("mouse")
    set mouse=a
endif
```

In `vimdiff` this allows to easily scroll long files, but the text is not kept in the scrollback, although it does for single files.

Comment: So I take it that the main motivation is scrolling with your mouse instead of within vim? You could try `:set mouse=a` to scroll within vim with your mouse or use gvim/macvim. I know it's not exactly what you asked, but I figured I'd float the idea out there in case it meets your needs.

Comment: @MattBoehm, as I said, the main motivation is to keep the changes on screen so I can review them if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

it might work using:

```
:set lines=1000 columns=100
```

where your line number is your scrollback limit.

Otherwise, you can "cheat" using screen, setting it to a way higher height than vim's default. I'm sure that there is a config option to set LINES and COLUMNS (as it does not use the env variables), but using a terminal to set it with a very small font, and opening it in another terminal using `screen -x` should work.

edit:

though, I do not really see why you'd want to abuse the scrollback, when vim can properly manage the mouse within the terminal. Just do `:set mouse=a` to have it take over full mouse control.

Comment: `:set lines=1000 columns=100` just mixes up the layout (please, try it yourself), a little less if I only set the number of lines. Could you explain your approach with `screen`? It's been ages since I last used it.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Window-Size

Comment: @zmo, I use the trackpad, not a mouse. I want to keep changes on-screen. That's why I mentioned I disabled `alternate screen`.